# How to pass a link in select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Case is I have to make a drop down in which i want link. for example

`<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %>, <%= link_to 'Show', edit_user_path(user) %>,  <td><%= link_to 'Edit  Contact', :action => :edit, :controller => :primary_contacts, :id => xyz %></td>`.

Any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you relly mean to ask is how to create a drop-down navigation menu -- right?  There are many ways to do that, and most of them do not involve a `select` element.  Usually, you would use CSS or JavaScript to show an absolute-positioned element containing your list of links when the user hovers over or clicks on the main element.

Comment: you are right but suppose i have 10 usr on my index page, everytime i hover on any user dropdown pop up only on top(for 1st user). i am new to ruby rails....